# How can I get the latest data from table using group by in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In my table there is total five entries of two users "joo" and "foo". I need to select last data row of these users. I have tried query but getting the first value only.

eg: `joo` last data row is `id 3`.
    `foo` last data row is `id 5`.

I need data of `id 3 and 5`.

**Query**

```
    SELECT id, company, title, firstname, street,  
           postal, city,  country, phone, payment_type
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY firstname
```

**I am getting Result**

```
id company title firstname street  postal city  country phone payment_type
1   BMW    test1  joo       test1  test1  test1 test1   1234  online
4   BMW    test4  foo       test4  test4  test4 test4   6666  amazone
```

**FUll table**

```
id company title firstname street  postal city  country phone payment_type
1   BMW    test1  joo       test1  test1  test1 test1   1234  online
2   BMW    test2  joo       test2  test2  test2 test2   1233  amazone
3   BMW    test3  joo       test3  test3  test3 test3   5555  paypal
4   BMW    test4  foo       test4  test4  test4 test4   6666  amazone
5   BMW    test5  foo       test5  test5  test5 test5   7777  paypal
```

Comment: Try editing your question to include table schema and sample data in textual format.

Comment: Those screenshots aren't conveying a whole lot of information and can't be read, searched, copy-pasted or anything useful. Try to include plain-text whenever possible.

Comment: @tadman I have updated my question.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I have added data in textual format

Comment: Way easier to read, nice. It's all clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT id, company, title, firstname, street,  
               postal, city,  country, phone, payment_type
        FROM orders where id in( SELECT max(id) from orders group by firstname );
```